# EF Code First: One-to-One One-way Relationship

Tags: ef-code-first

I regularly have the following structure:

```
MyClass
public virtual ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }
public virtual Version CurrentVersion { get; set; }
```

That is, there is a list of stuff, and some class both points to that list, and one specific item in that list - either the current version of many versions, the next upcoming event in a list of events, etc.

In my schema what I'd like to end up with is a Foreign Key pointing from Version to MyClass - that much works out properly. But then I'd like a Foreign Key pointing from MyClass to Version representing the CurrentVersion property, with no Foreign Key pointing back - I don't want the extra storage or bother of telling a Version what MyClass it's the CurrentVersion for, if any. Put another way, I'd like this second relationship to be one-way from MyClass to Version, even though it's one-to-one.

What EF Code First gives me instead is the normal one-to-many on the first property, with the FK from Version to MyClass, but then a full one-to-one relationship on the second property with an FK pointing in both directions - so the underlying schema for Version ends up with MyClass_Id and MyClass_Id1.

So, is there a way to get a one-way relationship in EF Code First without resorting to the Fluent API? It looked like maybe System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.InverseProperty had a shot at it, but it didn't seem to offer a way to say "Don't generate one."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to specify the InverseProperty on the property that points back, so that EF realizes it's to the Many-to-Many, not to the One-to-One.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Version CurrentVersion { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }
}

public class Version
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Versions")]
    public Versioned Versioned { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: would you please tell me how can I do it with fluent api?

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee Probably best as its own question